# Two way communication over a socket while listening

Tags: python, sockets

I want to be able to listen for messages on a socket continuously as I have data coming into the program irregularly. However I also have a need to send data on a button click. Is there any way to do this over one socket?

I have tried to connect two sockets to the same IP address but it tells me I'm not allowed.

Comment: There's no issue sending and receiving on a single socket. Do you need to listen for new connections?

Comment: Yes it is possible. Check the [Python Socket Tutorial](https://realpython.com/python-sockets/) and [Python Socket Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html). I think you will need to take a look at multithreading in Python too.

Comment: Yes? Did you try it? Just send and receive using the same socket.